# How to loop through all tables in a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, foreach

I would want to loop through all the tables in a database using C# and list them in a listBox1 (preferably a `foreach` loop):

[image: SSMS screenshot]

I CANNOT just create a local list of tables names, because they are constantly being added/removed.

Could someone provide an example?

BTW: no I'm not creating a software for pirated movies

Comment: it depends on the database engine, but you can usually issue queries to something like sys_tables. What DB?

Comment: Microsoft SQL database with Server Management Studio

Comment: https://www.datameer.com/blog/sql_how-to-display-all-the-tables-from-a-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using C#, have a look at [SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-ver16). Here's a demonstration via powershell (which is an expedient way for me to demonstrate):

```
$db_server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server .;
$db = $db_server.Databases['AdventureWorks2019'];
$tables = $db.Tables;
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother adding a reference to another library for something that can be done from a simple SELECT

Answer (score 1):

See if this works after logging into SQL Server database:

```
select schema_name(t.schema_id) as schema_name,
       t.name as table_name,
       t.create_date,
       t.modify_date
from sys.tables t
order by schema_name,
         table_name;
```

If you can get it working to produce the fields you want, then you just need to write the code to do it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic C# script to run SQL.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace sqltest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try 
            { 
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.DataSource = "<your_server>.database.windows.net"; 
                builder.UserID = "<your_username>";            
                builder.Password = "<your_password>";     
                builder.InitialCatalog = "<your_database>";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nQuery data example:");
                    Console.WriteLine("=========================================\n");

                    String sql = "SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
                            }
                        }
                    }                    
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a SQL script to list all tables and all fields in SQL Server.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```